An error occurred: Unable to retrieve security descriptor for this frame
I am trying to post an image in third party tool using below code, but getting an error" An error occurred: Unable to retrieve security descriptor for this frame."
Can any one please help me, how to resolve this and what exactly that error meaning? Thank you in advance
<script runat="server">
  Platform.Load("Core", "1.1.5");

  var imageBase64 = "data:image/jpeg;base64,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";
  var textMessage = "Sample Post Text";
  var accessToken = "XXX";  // Replace with your actual access token
  var ownerUrn = "urn:li:person:XXX";  // Replace with your person URN

  if (textMessage && imageBase64) {
    try {
      // Step 1: Register the upload
    var apiEndpoint = "https://api.linkedin.com/v2/assets?action=registerUpload";
var registerUploadPayload = '{"registerUploadRequest": {"recipes": ["urn:li:digitalmediaRecipe:feedshare-image"], "owner": "urn:li:person:XXX", "serviceRelationships": [{"relationshipType": "OWNER", "identifier": "urn:li:userGeneratedContent"}]}}';

                            var registerReq = new Script.Util.HttpRequest(apiEndpoint);
                            registerReq.method = "POST";
                            registerReq.emptyContentHandling = 0;
                            registerReq.retries = 2;
                            registerReq.continueOnError = true;
                            registerReq.contentType = "application/json";
                            registerReq.setHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken);
                            registerReq.postData = registerUploadPayload;
                            var registerResp = registerReq.send();
                            var registerRespJson = Platform.Function.ParseJSON(registerResp.content);
                            var uploadUrl = registerRespJson.value.uploadMechanism["com.linkedin.digitalmedia.uploading.MediaUploadHttpRequest"].uploadUrl;
                            var assetUrn = registerRespJson.value.asset;

                            var imageUploadReq = new Script.Util.HttpRequest(uploadUrl);
                            imageUploadReq.method = "PUT";
                            imageUploadReq.emptyContentHandling = 0;
                            imageUploadReq.retries = 2;
                            imageUploadReq.continueOnError = true;
                            imageUploadReq.contentType = "application/octet-stream";
                            imageUploadReq.postData = Base64Decode(imageBase64);
                            var imageUploadResp = imageUploadReq.send();

                            var apiEndpointPost = "https://api.linkedin.com/v2/ugcPosts";
                            var payload = '{"author": "urn:li:person:XXX","lifecycleState": "PUBLISHED","specificContent": {"com.linkedin.ugc.ShareContent": {"shareCommentary": {"text": "' + textMessage + '"},"shareMediaCategory": "IMAGE","media": [{"status": "READY","description": {"text": "' + textMessage + '"},"originalUrl": "' + assetUrn + '","title": {"text": "' + textMessage + '"}}]}},"visibility": {"com.linkedin.ugc.MemberNetworkVisibility": "PUBLIC"}}';

                            var req = new Script.Util.HttpRequest(apiEndpointPost);
                            req.method = "POST";
                            req.emptyContentHandling = 0;
                            req.retries = 2;
                            req.continueOnError = true;
                            req.contentType = "application/json";
                            req.setHeader("X-Restli-Protocol-Version", "2.0.0");
                            req.setHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken);
                            req.postData = payload;
                            var resp = req.send();
                            Platform.Response.Write('Response: ' + resp.content);
                        } catch (ex) {
                            Platform.Response.Write("An error occurred: " + ex.message + "<br>");
                        }
                    }</script>

